# Get Feature For org.eclipse.ui.ide.application

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I constantly have the problem that I need a specified plug-in but can't find the feature Eclipse uses to ship it, thus adding the plug-in, then dependency 1, dependency 2, dependency 3, dependency 1 of dependency 1, etc. all one by one.

There is no documentation of any kind, and even if you miraculously guessed a feature name you can't access the feature's contents (like in the Plug-ins View or in the Target Platform). They even seem to have hidden their source code, so you can't search the XML files manually.

So how do I get the feature(s) an Eclipse plug-in belongs to?

If there is no way to get this information (knowing Eclipse, this might just be true), the current Feature I'm searching for is the one of `org.eclipse.ui.ide.application`. What is its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.ui.ide.application` is in the `org.eclipse.platform` feature.

All the feature.xml files are in the 'features' directory of your Eclipse installation.

Comment: I have Eclipse Neon, there is no features directory anymore. Plug-ins and features now get scattered on the hard drive :(

Comment: I also have Eclipse Neon and I do have a features directory. I think if you use the version with the Oomph installer it behaves differently - I don't use this.